# Connecting to Redshift via psycopg2 fails

Tags: python, ip, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I have whitelisted ec2 IP address but without 0.0.0.0/0 configuration, I can't connect to the Redshift database from psycopg2. What can be done about this situation where we want to request from a particular IP address.

Is this is the bug that exists when you try to connect it programmatically

Edit:

I tried to whitelist my local IP address and ran my program on the local server and it got connected. But I am not able to connect via my application hosted on EC2 instance.

Comment: This looks like a continuation of [database - How to configure specific IP address in psycopg2 request? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63274691/how-to-configure-specific-ip-address-in-psycopg2-request). If it works for `0.0.0.0/0`, then it should work if you use your IP address in the Security Group.

Comment: You should test it by connecting with an SQL client from your own computer to verify that it works.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein. Thanks will try this approach

Comment: you must update your question with more details! however check which port you are specifying (likely should be 5439) also check that you made the cluster publicly accessible